# GDocs Script to fetch web info behind a form using UrlFetchApp

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to fetch some web data using GDocs but the data is behind a form so I need to post some data to the form to get the result. (So I cant use ImportXML etc)
The function that I am trying to use is https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app but I dont really know where to start since I don't have much java script experience.
Is there anyone that has a script that takes an url, form name & the data to post that can be used in GDocs?

Answer (score 0):

There's an example of such a script here: [How do I use Google Apps Script to change a CSS page to one with inline styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004225/how-do-i-use-google-apps-script-to-change-a-css-page-to-one-with-inline-styles/20689529#20689529).

It's a different application, but the method applies. Here's a skeleton function to get you started.

The `payload` object should contain the name / value pairs of the form data you want to simulate. The `url` should be changed to match the site you're submitting the form to. Once you've made the `POST` request by the call to `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`, you should be able to parse the response using the `getElementByVal()` utility from [Does Google Apps Script have something like getElementById?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695034/does-google-apps-script-have-something-like-getelementbyid/16702114#16702114).

```
function postForm() {
  // Generate a POST request with form data.
  var payload =
  {
    "name" : 'Anonymous Person',   // Replace with relevant name / value pairs
    "town" : "Springfield"
  };

  // Because payload is a JavaScript object, it will be interpreted as
  // an HTML form. (We do not need to specify contentType; it will
  // automatically default to either 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  // or 'multipart/form-data')

  var options =
  {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload,
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true
  };

  var url = "http://form.somewhere.com";   // Replace as appropriate
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  // Put the receieved xml response into XMLdocument format
  var xml = response.getContentText();
  var doc = XmlService.parse(xml);

  // Extract the details you want...
  var someData = getElementByVal( doc, 'textarea', 'name', 'text' );

  ...
}
```