# Google Apps Script, UrlFetchApp and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I would like to load a web page every day (perhaps more times a day), parse its data and email results.

To parse the web page I am using a `parse.gs` script like the following:

```
var url="http://http://example.com";
var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
var XmlDoc = Xml.parse(page, true);
```

When I parse `XmlDoc` I have only getElement/s functions available and I find it difficult to do an effective job. So I would like to use something more productive, like the JQuery selectors.

As far as I understood I have to add a jquery.html page to the project like:

```
<html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Then add to `parse.gs` the function:

```
function doGet() {
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('jquery');
}
```

After calling `doGet`, how do I parse `XmlDoc`?  Using lines like `$('#content').html(XmlDoc);` doesn't work.

Comment: You're not restricted to using `.getElement()` to navigate an XML structure - one you have *any element* you can reference its properties as you would any javascript object. You didn't ask for an alternative, but there you go.

Comment: Well `getElementById` is not available, as far as I know. Anyway  alternative to jquery is welcomed.

Comment: If you're looking for an item with a specific ID, you could do a regex search to extract what you want.

Comment: WRT `getElementById`, check out the utility in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16702114/1677912). A practical example of its use is in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16860598/1677912).

Comment: @Frederic: if you want to get a div and it has many nested divs, with regex it is quite difficult because you have many </div> and you have to count the opening div a closing div.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to jquery, try building on the capabilities of the Xml Service entirely in apps-script.

[A previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695034/does-google-apps-script-have-something-like-getelementbyid/16702114#16702114) introduced a utility function that locates elements in the XML Document by searching for properties matching the search criteria.

```
getElementByVal( body, 'input', 'value', 'Go' )  

... will find
  <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Go" id="btn" class="submit buttonGradient" />
```

It also showed one possible specialization, for searching 'id' attributes of `<div>`s:

```
getDivById( html, 'tagVal' )

... will find <div id="tagVal">
```

If you are able to identify an element uniquely, as in the above examples, a simple script can get you that element easily:

```
var url="http://http://example.com";
var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
// Get <div id="content">
var contentDiv = getDivById( pageDoc.getElement().body, 'content' );
...
```