# How to extract chart tool tip values from a web page using Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Looking at [this chart](http://www.barchart.com/chart.php?sym=DXU13&t=BAR&size=M&v=2&g=1&p=I:5&d=L&qb=1&style=technical&template=):

- I would like to extract the volume information at a given point in time (the volume is shown in the chart title, when the cursor is moved across the volume chart) – e.g:

  ```
  [Fri. Jul 26, 2013 13:25:00] Volume 118
  ```
- which is stored on the chart as:

  ```
  < area shape="rect" coords="541,463,542,471" onmousemove="showStudyTooltip(event, 'B', '[Fri. Jul 26, 2013 13:25:00]', 'Volume', '118.0000000')" >
  ```

How can this been done?

Note that it is not only 'Volume' that I want to extract, but also different indicator values that can be added beneath the volume chart.

PS Among others I have search for inspiration the following places (but been unable to come up with a solution):

- [Does Google Apps Script have something like getElementById?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695034/does-google-apps-script-have-something-like-getelementbyid)
- http://www.distilled.net/blog/distilled/guide-to-google-docs-importxml/

Answer (score 2):

The data you're looking for isn't really well-formed for automated extraction, but we can work with it. The `getElementByVal()` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16702114/1677912) can be refactored to create `getElementsByVal()`, which will return an array of all matching document elements, giving us something to do further searching in.

```
/**
 * Traverse the given XmlElement, and return an array of matches.
 * Note: 'class' is stripped during parsing and cannot be used for
 * searching, I don't know why.
 * <pre>
 * Example: getElementsByVal( body, 'input', 'value', 'Go' ); will find
 * 
 *          <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Go" id="btn" class="submit buttonGradient" />
 * </pre>
 *
 * @param {XmlElement} element XML document element to start search at.
 * @param {String}     id      HTML <div> id to find.
 *
 * @return {[XmlElements]}     All matching elements (in doc order).
 */
function getElementsByVal( element, elementType, attr, val ) {

  var results = [];
  // If the current element matches, remember it.
  if (element[attr] 
      && element[attr] == val
      && element.getName().getLocalName() == elementType) {
    results.push( element );
  }

  // Check element's children
  var elList = element.getElements();
  var i = elList.length;
  while (i--) {
    // (Recursive) Check each child, in document order.
    results = results.concat(getElementsByVal( elList[i], elementType, attr, val ));
  }
  // Return summary of matches
  return results;
}
```

To make use of this new helper function, what if we create a function `getIndicators()` that accepts a String parameter containing the point in time we're interested in - `Mon. Jul 29, 2013 07:40:00` for example? The matching text will be found in an `area` element that's got `shape="rect"`, and we'll find it inside an attribute called `onmousemove`. Here's our function:

```
function getIndicators(timeString) {
  var txt = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.barchart.com/chart.php?sym=DXU13&t=BAR&size=M&v=2&g=1&p=I:5&d=L&qb=1&style=technical&template=").getContentText();
  var doc = Xml.parse(txt,true);
  var body = doc.html.body;
  var indicators = "not found";

  // Look for elements matching: < area shape="rect" ... >
  var chartPoints = getElementsByVal(body, 'area', 'shape', 'rect');

  // Search for the chartPoint with tooltip containing the time we care about
  for (var i=0; i<chartPoints.length; i++) {
    if (chartPoints[i].onmousemove.indexOf(timeString) > -1) {
      // found our match
      indicators = chartPoints[i].onmousemove;
    }
  }

  return indicators
}
```

As it stands, it will return the entire text value assigned to `onmousemove`; the exercise of parsing that intelligently is left to you.

Here's a test function to help:

```
function test_getIndicators() {
  Logger.log( getIndicators("Mon. Jul 29, 2013 07:40:00" ) );
}
```

When run, here's the log (today, anyway...):

```
[13-07-29 16:47:47:266 EDT] showOHLCTooltip(event, 'B', '[Mon. Jul 29, 2013 07:40:00]', 'DXU13', '81.8050000', '81.8300000', '81.8000000', '81.8200000')
```

Comment: Mogsdad, thank you so much your detailed and informative answer. This is exactly what I was looking for (and that I failed to produce myself after countless hours in front of my computer). It works perfectly! I really appreciate you taking the time and effort to help me out & thanks to stackoverflow.com for having such a great site - it has really helped me out many times, when looking for answers to concrete coding problems.