# How to extract value from AtomPub XML HTTP response in Javascript (for Google Apps Admin Settings API)

Tags: javascript, xml, google-apps-script, atom-feed, atompub

I am calling the [Google Apps Admin Settings API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings/#retrieving_the_maximum_number_of_users_in_a_domain) from a Google Apps Script script (Javascript) to retrieve the maximum number of users in our Google Apps domain.

A successful GET request returns the response in AtomPub XML format, like so:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:apps='http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006'>
<id>https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/2.0/domain.com/general/maximumNumberOfUsers</id>
<updated>2014-07-16T00:55:27.837Z</updated>
<link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/2.0/domain.com/general/maximumNumberOfUsers'/>
<link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/2.0/domain.com/general/maximumNumberOfUsers'/>
<apps:property name='maximumNumberOfUsers' value='100'/></entry>
```

The value of the **maximumNumberOfUsers** property (in this case it's *100*) is the only part I care about.

How do I extract that value so I can assign it to an integer variable?

My first instinct was to write a crazy complex regex but I KNOW there must be an easier way!

I think there's a way to do this with JQuery, but there's no way to use jQuery in Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read over [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695034/does-google-apps-script-have-something-like-getelementbyid/16702114#16702114). No need to write crazy regex... just pick up that utility that deals with the xml structure directly!

Here's an untested piece of code that uses the `getElementByVal()` function from that answer:

```
...
var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
var root = document.getRootElement();
var atom = XmlService.getNamespace('http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
var entries = document.getRootElement().getChildren('entry', atom);

var maxUsers = getElementByVal( entries, 'property', 'name', 'maximumNumberOfUsers' );
                    .getAttribute(value);
...
```